# Script to send me an e-mail and reboot tomcat attack DDOS

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tomcat, monitoring

I need help to have a script to send me an e-mail alert when system resource intensive CPU and memory. I would also be interested in a script that when the tomcat is reaching the limits of its resources reboot my pc (This script would be to prevent DDOS attacks).

I wish you could help me !! Thank you

Comment: [What yave you tried so far?](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: How would that prevent DDOS attacks? If you reboot your server and the attacks continue, then you reboot again? Putting your machine in a boot loop and having no service, and as such the DDOS was successful.

Comment: Restart tomcat, not the server.. In the tomcat instead of "kill" the process, reboot the tomcat

Comment: sudo service tomcat6 restart

Comment: automatically, not manually. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION!!!!

Here is the script of which I spoke. This script will automatically restart the Tomcat when it exceeds 95% of physical memory. Enjoy it !!

porcentaje=95

usoMemoria=$(ps aux | grep tomcat | grep -v grep | awk '{printf ("%.0f", $4)}')

if [ $usoMemoria -ge $porcentaje ]; then

echo "Se ha superado el tope (95%) de memoria que se ha establecido para el Tomcat. Se procede a su reinicio automatico"

echo "$(date)"

echo "Comenzando..."

service tomcat7 restart

echo "Terminando Script..."

fi

exit 0